# Infinityscroll typescript/angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, scroll

I'm setting up this angular4 app, getting data from an API.
I'm trying to set up an easy infinity scroll, and its working, but the initial pagecontent is loaded twice. How do i avoid this from being loaded twice?
The HTML part just runs the (scrolled)="onScroll()" function, so i didnt include that.
Thanks!

discover.component.ts:

```
export class DiscoverComponent implements OnInit {
  stories: any;
  resultHits: Array<Object>;
  page:any;
  feed:any;
  hits:string;

  constructor(private storiesService: StoriesService) {}


  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getLatestFeed() {
    this.page = 0;
    this.feed = 'latest';
    this.hits = '6';
    console.log("latest feed");
    this.getFeed(this.page, this.feed, this.hits);
  }

  getCuratedFeed() {
    this.page = 0;
    this.feed = 'curated';
    this.hits = '6';
    this.getFeed(this.page, this.feed, this.hits);
    console.log("curated feed");
  }

  getTrendingFeed() {
    this.page = 0;
    this.feed = 'trending';
    this.hits = '6';
    this.getFeed(this.page, this.feed, this.hits);
    console.log("trending feed");
  }

  onScroll() {
    this.getMore(this.page, this.feed, this.hits);
  }

  //Get the latest feed

  private getFeed(page, feed, hits) {
    this.storiesService.getFeed(this.page, this.feed, this.hits).then((data) => {
      this.stories = data;
      this.stories = this.stories.hits;
      this.resultHits = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < this.stories.length; i++) {
        console.log(this.stories[i])
        if (i < this.stories.length) {
          this.resultHits.push(this.stories[i]);
        }
      }
      console.log(this.stories);
    });
  }

  //Scroll
  private getMore(page, feed, hits) {
    this.storiesService.getFeed(this.page, this.feed, this.hits).then((data) => {
      this.page++;
      this.stories = data;
      this.stories = this.stories.hits;
      for (var i = 0; i < this.stories.length; i++) {
        console.log(this.stories[i])
        if (i < this.stories.length) {
          this.resultHits.push(this.stories[i]);
        }
      }
      console.log(this.stories);
    });
  }
}
```

stories.component.ts:

```
export class StoriesService implements OnInit {

  private stories: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  //Get 6 latest story feeds
  getFeed(page: any, feed: string, hits: string) {

    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then((idToken) => {
        let headers = new HttpHeaders()
          .set('user_token', idToken);
        let params = new HttpParams()
          .set('page', page)
          .set('feed', feed)
          .set('hits', hits)
        console.log(params);
        this.http.get('https://dev-api.byrd.news/v1/stories', { params, headers })
          .toPromise()
          .then(data => {
            resolve(data);
          })
      }, error => {
        reject(error);
      })
    })
    return promise;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<app-top-nav></app-top-nav>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <li class="navbar-right"><a (click)="getCuratedFeed()">Curated</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-right"><a (click)="getTrendingFeed()">Trending</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-right"><a (click)="getLatestFeed()">Latest</a></li>

    <li class="navbar-right"><a routerLink="/map" routerLinkAcive="active">Map</a></li>

  </div>
</nav>

<h1>DiscoverComponent</h1>



<h2> {{feed}} </h2>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12" *ngFor="let story of resultHits">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img *ngIf="story.storyMediaType === 'image'" class="img-fluid" src="{{story.storyThumbnailImage}}" />
      <div class="caption">
        <p>{{story.storyCity}}, {{story.storyCountry}}</p>
        <h3>{{story.storyHeadline}}</h3>
        <p>Uploadet {{story.uploadDate}}</p>
        <p>Bruger: {{story.userDisplayName}}</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Like</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div infiniteScroll [infiniteScrollDistance]="2" [infiniteScrollThrottle]="1000" (scrolled)="onScroll()">

</div>

<div class="notification is-warning" *ngIf="finished">
  <p>Ikke mere materiale!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something along these lines, removing some duplicate code and locking the scroll function while the page property is 0;

```
export class DiscoverComponent {
    stories: any;
    resultHits: Array<Object>;
    page:any = 0;
    feed:any;
    hits:string;

    constructor(private storiesService: StoriesService) {} 

    getInitialFeed(feed) {
        this.getFeed(0, feed, '6');
        this.page = 1;
    }   

    onScroll() {
        if(this.page > 0) {
            this.getFeed(this.page, this.feed, this.hits);
        }
    }

    private getFeed(page, feed, hits) {
        this.storiesService.getFeed(page, feed, hits).then((data) => {
            this.stories = data;
            this.stories = this.stories.hits;
            this.resultHits = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < this.stories.length; i++) {
                this.resultHits.push(this.stories[i]);            
            }
        });
        if(page > 0) this.page++;
    } 
}
```

Html:

```
<li class="navbar-right"><a (click)="getInitialFeed('curated')">Curated</a></li>
<li class="navbar-right"><a (click)="getInitialFeed('trending')">Trending</a></li>
<li class="navbar-right"><a (click)="getInitialFeed('latest')">Latest</a></li>
```

Also you can (but might not need to) add a @Hostlistener on the onScrol function like so:

```
import { Component, HostListener} from "@angular/core";
..
@HostListener("window:scroll")
    onScroll() {
        if(this.page > 0) {
            this.getFeed(this.page, this.feed, this.hits);
        }
    }
```

Edit: it might also be a good idea to lock the onScroll function while it is triggered and not done loading.

Comment: Thank you! The feed still loads from the API, but i get this error 300+ times: "core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]"

Comment: is the module properly registered? import { HttpModule }  from '@angular/http';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        HttpModule ]
})

Comment: You mean in app.component? Yes!

Comment: I tried some stuff, and it doesn't seem to work without the repetitive code i wrote mate.

Comment: No you register modules in modules, probably the app.module.ts

Comment: Yes, sorry, i meant the app.module.ts file. I already did that.

Comment: Still getting the error. Does it have something to do with, im working with promises and not observables?